# Which Visual Studio component contain the MSVC Hostx files?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, docker-for-windows, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

My `.NET` solution contains an `editbin` command in `PostBuild` events.

We try to create a *Docker Container* for compiling our solution. To do that, we installed the `VS17` with the [installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2017#step-5-create-and-build-the-dockerfile).

We can't find which [component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?view=vs-2017) we should select to get the `editbin`.

In my machine, the `editbin` exist in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Host{x86/x64}\{x86/x64/arm64}` in 6 places- all the compinations of the placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editbin` is part of the C++ build toolchain, along with `cl` (the compiler), `link` (the linker), `rc` (the resource compiler), and other such tools for creating/modifying binaries. That's why you find it in "...\VC\Tools..." subdirectory.

As such, this would be in the ["Visual Studio Build Tools 2017"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2017) component:

> The Visual Studio Build Tools allows you to build native and managed MSBuild-based applications without requiring the Visual Studio IDE. There are options to install the Visual C++ compilers and libraries, MFC, ATL, and C++/CLI support.

Note that you do not need to install Visual Studio in order to get this. You could just as well install [the Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

Comment: I installed the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64` and it install the `editbin`. The component `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17134` not install the `editbin`